# Which Stack Exchange site should questions about configuring office networks be asked on?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm after some networking help re: configuring our small / medium office network.

Previously, I've asked questions like this at ServerFault, and have been that was not the place for noobie questions. (No, I'm not going to link/talk about past questions, here).

Can someone please direct me to where I could ask my question(s) ?

Answer (score 3):

Server Fault may be the right place to ask but it kind of depends on what you're asking. If you have specific questions regarding your design/configuration, you'll likely be ok. If however you want SF to design your network then that won't go down so well.

There is also Network Engineering. I don't play that game so can't comment on how it's players will react to you question.

Comment: Interesting. It is a specific question about connecting two switches. My gut reaction was to ask on SF but my general feeling there is ... unless you're a pro, get lost. :( (For The Record: I've been a member of SF since (literally) day 1, when it was opened).

Comment: SF accepts questions within a business environment (exclusions apply). We expect people to have done some of their own research and to show that (if applicable).

Comment: Kewl. lets see how I go this time :/ (yes, I've tried to provide info about what I've tried. It's also about fibre, so hopefully that also prooves it's for an office, not a home or a school-question.